# Trouble calling a method in its own class

Tags: c#, console

I'm so sorry if this is very obvious or if this question doesn't fit the site's question rules.

In the following example, how would I make my `Main` method call my `AverageThree` method? The following doesn't work:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        public double AverageThree(double one, double two, double three)
        {
            return (one * two * three) / 3;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(AverageThree(3.7, 56, 998.321));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your class `Program` you have two types of functions:

- static functions:  `Main()`
- instance functions:  `AverageThree()`

And `Main()` is the entry point to your application.  And it must be static.

From an static function you only can access to static content.  Then, one solution is to convertr `AverageThree()` as static (second solution).

The other solution is to create an instance of `Program`, and call the function `AverageThree()`.

You could create an instance of your class Program:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        public double AverageThree(double one, double two, double three)
        {
            return (one * two * three) / 3;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine(p.AverageThree(3.7, 56, 998.321));
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can convert method `AverageThree`to static:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        public static double AverageThree(double one, double two, double three)
        {
            return (one * two * three) / 3;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(AverageThree(3.7, 56, 998.321));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind, could you explain to me why a public class couldn't be used in its class without creating an instance first? Why wouldn't the compiler realize that it is in the same class? or, does the visibility change the way a method is used through the whole program?

Comment: Non-static methods require an instance of the class to call them.  Static methods can only call static methods, even in their own class.  You can find some details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s35hcfh7.aspx) as a starting point.